# Tell ocamlbuild where to find module

Tags: linker, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have an OCaml project, for which I use `ocamlbuild`.
In this project, I have two subprojects, `subproject1` and `subproject2`.
`subproject2` needs to use a module called `Module` from `subproject1`.
To sum up, I have the following structure:

```
project/
|
|-- subproject1
|   |
|   |-- module.ml
|
|-- subproject2
    |
    |-- main.ml
```

If `module.ml` were located in `subproject2`, next to `main.ml`, I'd simply use the `open` directive in `subproject2/main.ml`:

```
(*subproject2/main.ml *)
open Module
```

But since `module.ml` is located in `subproject1`, how can I tell `ocamlbuild` to open `subproject1/module.ml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found any straightforward way to include or directly link a source file, I've come up with a way to effectively include a module from a sibling directory.

Once again, here is the structure of the project:

```
project/
|
|-- subproject1
|   |
|   |-- module.ml
|
|-- subproject2
    |
    |-- main.ml
```

From the `project` directory, the following `ocamlbuild` command will compile the whole project, with `subproject2/main.ml` as target, and `subproject2/_build/` as output build directory:

```
ocamlbuild -I subproject1 subproject2/_build/ subproject2/main.byte
```

The expected `main.byte` file will however be output as `subproject2/_build/subproject2/main.byte`, so manual link editing will be necessary to end up with the usual `main.byte` symlink in `subproject2`.

---

Since I like being able to use `make`, I wrote the following `Makefile` in `subproject2/`, so as to compile `subproject2/` by simply running `make` from the inside, as `make` is supposed to work.

```
all:
    # Move to project/
    cd ..;\
    # Run the ocamlbuild command
    ocamlbuild -I subproject1 subproject2/_build/ subproject2/main.byte\
    # Go back into subproject2
    cd subproject2;\
    # Try to remove the existing symlink, mute stderr, and continue on error
    rm main.byte 2> /dev/null || true;\
    # Create the desired symlink
    ln -s _build/subproject2/main.byte main.byte
```